# Не видит дочерний элемент

Tags: java, json, json-encode

Всем привет. Пытаюсь распарсить json файл, бьюсь с этим второй день уже, вылетают постоянно какие-то ошибки, попытаюсь спросить здесь. `proxy.getCurrencyRates(currency)` - метод, который возвращает json файл из внешнего ресурса. Вот код:

```
JSONObject response = proxy.getCurrencyRates(currency);
JSONArray rates = response.getJSONArray("rates");
```

При создании массива появляется след. ошибка:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["rates"] not found.
```

Физически этот элемент в файле есть:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1654646372,
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
        "RUB": 61.749995
    }
}
```

Использую библиотеку org.json. Пробовал использовать com.googlecode.json-simple, но там похожие проблемы с созданием массива. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: [getJSONObject, а не getJSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998203)

Answer (score 0):

массив в json выглядит так

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]
}
```

В этом примере это элемент cars

А у тебя элемен rates это вложеный объект.

Comment: Попробуй выполнить метод getJSONObject(rates)